# Vector fields generating the vector bundle $(TV)^{\bot}$ where $V$ is a submanifold of a cotangent bundle $T*X$

Tags: symplectic-geometry

Let $V$ be a submanifold of the cotangent bundle $T^*X$ of a smooth manifold $X$. Then we can consider the vector bundle $(TV)^{\bot}$ whose fiber is the symplectic orthogonal complement of a tangent space of $V$.

In some references, there is the statement: the vector bundle $(TV)^{\bot}$ is generated by Hamiltonian vector fields $X_f$ where $f$ vanishes on $V$.

I can check this in some particular cases. But I cannot prove this in general.
If you know about that, please teach me.

Comment: If $f$ vanishes on $V$, then $\omega(X_f,w)={\rm d}f(w)=0$ for all $w$ tangent to $V$, which means that $X_f$ is normal to $V$ whenever $f$ vanishes at $V$. Can you go on with this?

Comment: @IvoTerek Thanks a lot. But I don't know how to express any element in $(TV)^{\bot}$ as a finite sum of such hamiltonian vector fields.